# VBA: Offset doesn't work, rewriting current row

Tags: excel, vba

This is a snippet of my code:

```
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 25))
```

The idea was to open multiple workbooks in my dir, copy a certain range and paste that range into a master file.

The code seemed to be working just fine, except for the last couple of days. The offset function doesn't seem to be working properly anymore which causes my last copied line in my master file to be rewritten by new pastes instead of jumping down to the next empty row below.

For clarity's sake, the full code:

```
Sub LTD()
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim erow
    Dim Filepath As String

    Filepath = "C:\Map\" 
    MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        If MyFile = "File.xlsm" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
        Range("B60:D60").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Close

        erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 25))

        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What changed in the last couple days? Can you show us an example of a workbook that your code is handling as desired, and another workbook that produces the incorrect output?

Comment: According to memory, nothing was changed. In what form should I give you an example? Previously the macro did the following:
-Open a workbook in a directory
-Select and copy a range
-Close that workbook, paste the copied range into the workbook which has the macro running.

And it would loop through the 2nd, 3d and every other file within the directory untill it reached a certain workbook, where the macro would abort.

Comment: So it's a case of a certain file used to be processed by your code to produce the correct output, but now the exact same file, when used as input to the exact same code results in wrong output?

Comment: Thank you for trying to figure this out with me Mypetition.
If I understand your question correctly, then no. If that we're the case, then every new file which is being opened by the loop, and copying the selected range, pastes it over the same Row instead of offsetting the new copies to the empty rows below.

Comment: Would help if you could show more of your code.  There are several potential issues there but without more context it's difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: perhaps qualify that `Row` with the sheet that you want to count? `erow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row`

Comment: erow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
This doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Sub LTD()
    Dim wb As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim erow
    Dim Filepath As String

    Filepath = "C:\Map\"
    MyFile = Dir(Filepath) '<< think about adding a filetype filter here eg Dir(Filepath & "*.xlsx")

    Set shtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")'<< or the tab name where
                                               '   you want the data to go...

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        If MyFile <> "File.xlsm" Then

            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filepath & MyFile)

            'Option1: copy-paste
            wb.Sheets("Results").Range("B60:Z60").Copy _
                shtDest.Cells(shtDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            'Option2: copy values only
            With wb.Sheets("Results").Range("B60:Z60")
                shtDest.Cells(shtDest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0). _
                     Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            End With

            wb.Close False

        End If

        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

**NOTE** - using End(xlUp) to find the last populated row is only dependable if all cells in the first column have a value: if you have any blanks then this method may not give the desired results.

Comment: Can't seem to run this, I get run-time error 9, Subscript out of range.
Refers to this line:
Set shtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All Data")

Comment: That was a "for example" of how you would define the sheet to which the data is being appended.  EDIT: updated to "Sheet1"

Comment: ...and I'm assuming the destination sheet is in the workbook where the code is running.  If not, then you need to make an adjustment.

Comment: Sorry in advance for being a layman, but yes, the destination sheet (named Sheet1) is in the workbook where the code is running. But how would I need to define that codeline to make it work properly?

Comment: See my added comment above. You just need to edit "Sheet1" if that's not the tab name of the worksheet where the data is to be pasted.

Comment: So I've just named it "Sheet1", 

The code does run, by very rapidly and consecutively openining and closing the required files (presumably), but nothing is being copied or pasted.

Comment: Is there a specific sheet in each workbook from which the data should be copied?  I defaulted to copying from the first sheet.  I notice you used `Activesheet` but that's not a very reliable method to use...

Comment: Well ActiveSheet would do just fine here, but all the sheets do have a have a name nonetheless, "Results".

Comment: In that case you just need `wb.Sheets("Results").Range("B60:D60").Copy ...`

Comment: My good man, I'm incredibly grateful for your help so far. Everything seems to be working, except for one small error. The 'paste' that's being applied is the wrong kind. I'm getting #ref errors, I reckon pasting as 'value' would resolve this issue.

Comment: You're copying 3 cells (B60 to D60) but pasting to a range 25 columns wide - is there a reason for that?

Comment: That's an error in my original post, it's supposed to be B60:Z60. This has however been accounted for in my attempts to get the code up and running.

Comment: See my edit above - you can select one of those approaches

Comment: Not to be a bother, but I seem to be returning empty cells when pasting with both option 1 and option 2.

Comment: The range is B60:Z60 in the tab "Results" though, previously this seemed to work.

Comment: Unless you're able to share sample files there's not much else i can offer.